# Can i have some suggestions to Monitor WebRTC sessions?

Tags: webrtc

I am looking for monitor WebRTC based audio/video calls and conferences to integrate one of my already existing SIP monitoring Product. Can i have some suggestions to monitor the WebRTC sessions.
Thanks in advance and waiting for response.
Thanks & Regards
Sudhakar K.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.callstats.io/

This tool is built specifically for monitoring the webRTC sessions.

Comment: Yes Karthik i know that. But i am seeking for the suggestions to monitor without callstats.io, like call/conference duration, success full conferences/calls and failure conferences/calls